# Javascript Run prototype in another file

Tags: javascript

How can i Execute the Client.prototype.disconnect on another page of javascript code?
Maybe i just have to inherit it?
If yes, then how do i inherit it?
Thanks.

```
    function(Komanda, _, Helpers, Channels, Channel, ChannelView, ChannelsView, Message, Notice, NamesView, Popup, moment, uuid) {

      var Client = function(session) {
        var self = this;

        self.irc = window.requireNode("irc");
        self.options = session.attributes;
        self.options.stripColors = false;
        self.nick = session.attributes.nick;
        self.socket = null;

        self.session = session;

        self.retryCount = 300;
        self.retryCountCurrent = 0;
        self.retryFunction = null;
        self.attemptingReconnect = false;
        self.allowReconnect = true;

        self.topics = {};

        self.binded = false;

        self.channels = new Channels();
        self.channel = new Channel();

        self.channelsView = new ChannelsView({
          collection: self.channels,
          model: self.channel
        });

        self.views = [];

        $(".channel-item[data-name=\"Status\"]").removeClass("selected");
        $(".channel").hide();

        var c = new Channel({
          channel: "Status",
          topic: false,
          names: {},
          name: "Server Status",
          server: self.options.uuid,
          status: true,
          pm: false
        });

        self.channels.add(c);

        var view = new ChannelView({
          model: c
        });

        Komanda.current = {
          server: self.options.uuid,
          channel: "Status"
        };

        $(".channel-holder").append(view.render().el);
        var selector = $("#sidebar div.session[data-id=\"" + self.options.uuid + "\"]");
        if (selector.find(".channel-list").length > 0) {
          selector.find(".channel-list").replaceWith(self.channelsView.render().el);
        } else {
          selector.append(self.channelsView.render().el);
        }

        self._whois = {};

        return this;
      };
  Client.prototype.disconnect = function(callback) {
    var self = this;

    self.attemptingReconnect = false;

    self.socket.disconnect("quit message", function() {
      self.session.set("connectionOpen", false);

      self.clearViews();
      self.socket.conn.end();

      if (_.isFunction(callback)) {
        callback(self);
      }

    });
  };
```

Comment: More details would be necessary... However first suggestion would be to  call the parent function, declare Client either to be global variable or return that from the function call and then load the next JavaScript file after this one on browser... Only if you are running this in browser

Comment: if not in browser... require both files one after other... and then use them

Comment: it's not in browser

Comment: Then specify where you are using and include complete code as in where is second file and how you want to use it...